# show minimized window titles in GNOME Panel

Tags: gnome3, debian-jessie, gnome-panel

I'd like the titles of all the windows that are not focused to show up in the Panel (to the right of "Activities" and current window). Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Panel, select "Add to Panel".  Scroll down and pick "Window List", the click Add.  The minimized/iconized windows will show up.